# Subexponential algorithms that apply only one of factoring and discrete logarithm?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, reference-request, factoring, decryption, number-field-sieve

Shor (quantum polynomial), Number Field Sieve (subexponential), Pollard rho (square root) all have both factoring and discrete logarithm over $\mathbb F_p^*$ variants.

> What are the subexponential techniques that only applies to
>
> 1. balanced semiprime integer factoring but not to discrete logarithm over **some** cryptographically important structures including $\mathbb F_p^*$ and Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm?
> 2. balanced semiprime integer factoring but not to discrete logarithm over **all** cryptographically important structures including $\mathbb F_p^*$ and Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm?
> 3. discrete logarithm over **some** cryptographically important structure including $\mathbb F_p^*$ but not to balanced semiprime integer factoring?

Please provide references appropriately.

Comment: Index Calculus and Elliptic Curve Factoring.

Comment: @SEJPM I thought index calculus is sieve technique for discrete logarithm.

Comment: Index calculus indeed works for DLP.

Comment: What about the algebraic factoring algorithms such as the Pollard $p-1$ and Williams $p+1$ (which are efficient when the underlying primes are smooth)? I am not aware of their counterparts in the discrete-log setting.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer Possible.